# How to send a csv from my local machine HBASE using nifi?

Tags: database, hdfs, hbase, apache-nifi

I am very new to DBMS and nifi platforms.

I am learning it and now I want to send a .csv file with some data from my local machine to HBASE using nifi.

It would be good to know the steps to be followed.

Also, to run hbase do I also need to install HDFS ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you don't require HDFS to install HBASE. HBASE can be installed using your local file system also. It can be installed in different different modes. Find the link below on the same, by this you will get an idea of different installation modes.

[Install HBASE in different modes](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/hbase/hbase_installation.htm)

Also, you want to ingest data from CSV file to some HBASE table. You can use a couple of processors to do so. Please find the steps below :

1. **Read file :** [Get File Processor Details](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.15.3/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.GetFile/index.html)
2. **Parse CSV file :** [CSVReader Processor Details](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-record-serialization-services-nar/1.15.3/org.apache.nifi.csv.CSVReader/index.html)
3. **Put data into HBASE :** [PutHBaseCell](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-hbase-nar/1.15.3/org.apache.nifi.hbase.PutHBaseCell/index.html) OR [PutHbasejSON](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-hbase-nar/1.15.3/org.apache.nifi.hbase.PutHBaseJSON/index.html) OR [PutHbaseRecord](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-hbase-nar/1.15.3/org.apache.nifi.hbase.PutHBaseRecord/index.html) (Use appropriate processor as per your scenario)

Comment: i have a scenario let's say I have 3 different servers where a first server is a different machine that has all the CSV files then the second machine is my laptop where I will install nifi and the third server is another machine where Hadoop and habse are installed. Now how can I to send the CSV file from machine 1 to machine 3 using nifi in machine 2?

Comment: So, First of all there should be connectivity between all the servers / machines you have. Assuming that following is the solution --- if you want to get CSV files from machine 1 to machine 2 you can do it using sftp("FetchSFTP" processor). Then do your processing on machine 2. Then put the file in HDFS in machine 3 using the "PutHDFS" processor.

Comment: The first part getting file is working fine. Now how can I configure the IP address and password to put it in the base table running in machine 3? I cant see any IP address or host name category as well as password category inside put hdfs or put hbase record. I want to put directly to the base table running in machine 3.